# Xaml child listview autoscroll

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, scroll

Here is the .XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="IMManager.ImManagerWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="IMM Media Manager" 
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
        WindowState="Normal" 
        MaxWidth="720" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="AlternatingListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- setting up triggers for alternate background colors -->
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <!-- setting row height here -->
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="LvAlbums" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/downloads/Album}" Width="680" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="dt1">
                <StackPanel x:Name="spAlbum" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{Binding XPath=@Artist,StringFormat='Artist: {0}'}"
                        FontSize="16px"
                        />
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{Binding XPath=@Name,StringFormat='Album: {0}'}"
                        FontSize="16px"
                        />
                    <ListView x:Name="lvTracks" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingListViewItemStyle}"   AlternationCount="2">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Track" Width="460">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="trackName" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Width="450" LineHeight="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,3,0,0">
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Progress" Width="175">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25">
                                                <ProgressBar Foreground="GreenYellow" Name="PbStatus" Value="{Binding XPath=@Progress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,3,0,0" Width="165"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" LineHeight="25" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding XPath=@Info, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="165" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0"/>
                                            </Canvas>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
      <Label Name="lblStatus" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="16"></Label>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Album Download Screenshot]

The issue is when the currently downloading track is past the bottom of the screen, it doesn't scroll into view.

I'm trying to somehow use lvTracks.ScrollIntoView but I'm having trouble addressing lvTracks. I can address LvAlbums but that does me no good.

There can be multiple albums, each with it's own lvTracks listview.

Thank you.

Comment: Which lvTracks are you trying to locate? It's one per row in LvAlbums.

Comment: The lvTracks that is currently being downloaded. The screenshot is a completed transaction. Imagine the progress bars are empty and each track is downloaded one at a time with the progress bar being populated while the track is being downloaded.

Comment: How does that answer my question? You say that you somehow are "trying to somehow use lvTracks". And I wonder which instance of lvTracks that you are referring to as there are multiple.

Comment: Again, the active row whose progress bar is being currently populated.

Comment: So how do you keep track of the "active row" then?

Comment: The listviews are populated via xml (LvAlbums.DataContext=myXmlDocument). The xml is then read again for the download information -- html link, etc -- foreach (var item in album.Descendants("Item"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to inner `ListView` of a particlular visible row of the outer one using the `ItemContainerGenerator` and the `VisualTreeHelper` class, e.g.:

```
private void FindInnerListView(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = 0; //find the lvTracks at the first row (index = 0) of LvAlbums
    ListBoxItem lbi = LvAlbums.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as ListBoxItem;
    if (lbi != null)
    {
        ListView lvTracks = GetChildOfType<ListView>(lbi);
        if (lvTracks != null)
        {
            //lvTracks.ScrollIntoView();
        }
    }
}

private static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null) return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Make sure that the containers have actually been created before you call the `ContainerFromIndex` or `ContainerFromItem` method.

Comment: That's what I was missing. The VisualTreeHelp to return the child objects.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

And after all that I had an "oh, duh" moment. I just stuck everything in a ScrollView (SvMain) and used SvMain.ScrollToVerticalOffset.

Still, mm8 answered the actual question and gets the kudos.